# Executing Custom UDF in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have the following table in my Hive

```
>describe weblogs;
OK
originatingip           string                                      
clientidentity          string                                      
userid                  string                                      
time                    string                                      
requesttype             string                                      
requestpage             string                                      
httpprotocolversion     string                                      
responsecode            int                                         
responsesize            int                                         
referrer                string                                      
useragent               string                                      
Time taken: 1.065 seconds, Fetched: 11 row(s)
```

I have created a UDF in Java to map Ip addresses with Geo locations. Following is my UDF

```
package com.prithvi.hive.logprocessing.udf.ipgeo;
public class IpgeoHive extends UDF {

Text result = new Text();
String ipCountry, ipCity;

public Text evaluate(Text input) throws IOException {
    if(input==null)return null;
    URL database_path = getClass().getResource("/GeoLiteCity.dat");
    File file;
    try {
      file = new File(database_path.toURI());
    } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
      file = new File(database_path.getPath());
    }
    LookupService cl = new LookupService(file);
    Location location = cl.getLocation(input.toString());
    if (location != null) {
        ipCountry = location.countryName;
        ipCity = location.city;
    } else {
        ipCountry = "Unknown";
        ipCity = "Unknown";
    }
    result.set(ipCountry+"/"+ipCity);
    return result;
}
}
```

The above udf return results as expected when tested by passing dummy values in eclipse

After building the jar file, I run it in my sandbox using the following commands

```
ADD JAR MapReduce_Examples-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION IP2GEO AS 'com.prithvi.hive.logprocessing.udf.ipgeo.IpgeoHive';

SELECT originatingip, IP2GEO(originatingip) from weblogs limit 10;
```

***But the job fails with the following errors, I have no clue on how to solve this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.***

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:    Hive Runtime Error while processing  row{"originatingip":"25.198.250.35","clientidentity":"-","userid":"-","time":"[2014-07-19T16:05:33Z]","requesttype":"\"GET","requestpage":"/","httpprotocolversion":"HTTP/1.1\"","responsecode":404,"responsesize":1081,"referrer":"\"-\"","useragent":"\"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)\""}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:195)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"originatingip":"25.198.250.35","clientidentity":"-","userid":"-","time":"[2014-07-19T16:05:33Z]","requesttype":"\"GET","requestpage":"/","httpprotocolversion":"HTTP/1.1\"","responsecode":404,"responsesize":1081,"referrer":"\"-\"","useragent":"\"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)\""}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:550)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:177)
... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text com.prithvi.hive.logprocessing.udf.ipgeo.IpgeoHive.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text) throws java.io.IOException  on object com.prithvi.hive.logprocessing.udf.ipgeo.IpgeoHive@63c0b9c3 of class com.prithvi.hive.logprocessing.udf.ipgeo.IpgeoHive with arguments {25.198.250.35:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text} of size 1
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1241)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:182)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:166)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:793)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:793)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:540)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1217)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
at com.prithvi.hive.logprocessing.udf.ipgeo.IpgeoHive.evaluate(IpgeoHive.java:28)
... 23 more
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec*
```

Comment: pls add sample records from weblogs table to your question.Thanks

Comment: Which geoip library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that hive don't know the java string/Text.

You have to convert the java string/Text to hive string.

Use the below code.

```
private JavaStringObjectInspector stringInspector;
stringInspector = PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector;
String ip = stringInspector.getPrimitiveJavaObject(input);
```

Comment: I'm still  getting the same error : Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public  suggestions most welcome .. and @Omkar

Comment: @Prithvi514  did you resolve it by any other method ??